# How can I force Atom to display the active tab in a specific color?

Tags: css, tabs, atom-editor

I'm using Atom 1.11.1.

I'm not familiar with Atom or CSS in any significant way yet, so please don't take much for granted in explaining a solution.

I'd prefer not to download a special theme.

Comment: Why not use other editor?

Comment: working through a course which is based on Atom

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the theme you are using, but this worked for me in One Dark with Cobalt2 to set a background color and text color. YMMV as there may be icons and other things involved in tabs depending on the theme.

```css
ul.tab-bar > li.tab[is='tabs-tab'].active,
ul.tab-bar > li.tab[is='tabs-tab'].active > div.title {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

You would add this to your stylesheet. See the [Flight Manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks) for more on this.

You should also really upgrade. As of Atom 1.13, the Shadow DOM was removed, and that changed a lot about how custom styles work.

Comment: @mattf It would go in `styles.less` in your config. See updated answer. The documentation shows you how to access it on your platform.